# Find Formulas for $M^{n}$ of Matrix $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. $M$ is the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 \\
4 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So if $M=PDP^{-1}$ then it follows $M^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ where $P$ is made of the eigenvectors and $D$ is the diagonal of our eigenvalues (both of which were found starting with a char. polynomial).

My results:
$$
D =
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 0 \\
0 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
P^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
-2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
P =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So I believe (unless I'm completely on the wrong track here) that I've found $M^n$, but I'm unsure now how to get this in an acceptable $2 \times 2$ matrix for $M^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost home! Your $P^{-1}$, $P$, and $D$ look good. Now,

$M^n = PD^nP^{-1}$, as you've said, but what is $D^n$? Since $D$ is diagonal, this is easy to figure out. (If you're not sure, take $n$ as $2$, then as $3$, and a pattern will readily emerge.)

Once you have that, multiply $P$ and $P^{-1}$ to it in the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

you have $M = UDU^{-1}=\pmatrix{4&-2\\4&10} = \pmatrix{1&1\\-2&-1} \pmatrix{8&0\\0&6}\pmatrix{-1&-1\\2&1}$  now you can raise it the power of $n$ so that 
$$M^n = UD^nU^{-1} =\pmatrix{1&1\\-2&-1} \pmatrix{8^n&0\\0&6^n}\pmatrix{-1&-1\\2&1} =  \pmatrix{-8^n+2* 6^n&-8^n+6^n\\2* 8^n-2* 6^n&2* 8^n - 6^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

The useful thing is that $$D^n = \begin{bmatrix} 8 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 \end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix} 8^n & 0 \\ 0 & 6^n \end{bmatrix}$$.